# Counting contractions as one or two words

Tags: contractions

I read this in a product review, and it has been bugging me all day.

> Three words: it's really cheap.

"It's" is obviously a contraction of two words, but does it count as one or two words?

Comment: Pick a definition of word (or look up "it's" in a dictionary). If it's a word then 1, if not then 2.

Comment: I'd count "it's" as one word. It may be a contraction of two, but that contraction still forms a single word. According to [NOAD's definition of a word](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LivT2.png), "it's" would pass the single-word test.

Comment: If you're counting words in something you've written and you get paid by the word, it's two. Otherwise, it's one.

Comment: +1 that would bug me all day too. It IS going to bug me all day.

Comment: @Jay Although your comment is amusing, I feel compelled to point out that it is not actually correct.

Comment: @tchrist Hmm. Perhaps I need to explain that "to get to the other side" is not an adequate explanation of why the chicken crossed the road, because it fails to explain why the chicken wanted to get to the other side. That's why we call it a "joke". Like my comment. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS Word and the concordoncer I’m using count them as one. Some dictionaries may count them as two. It all depends on what your purpose is in counting.

Comment: Barrie, what is a "concordoncer"? I looked it up in two online dictionaries and on Google and could not find an obvious definition.

Comment: @JAM http://www.lextutor.ca/concordancers/ What else is Google for, ha!

Comment: @JAM: It's software that allows an electronically stored corpus to be interrogated for lexical and grammatical features.

Comment: "MS Word counts them as one" is a pretty weak argument, in my opinion. The English language and its grammar were evolved by humans for humans, and MS Word does its best to keep up, but it's certainly not an expert.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, "*It's*" is obviously a **contraction** of two words

... into **one**, right?

Where's the doubt, then?

In the given context, it is beyond question that "*It's*" is one word.

In a different context where you may be concerned with serious lexical parsing, you may need to treat it as two words, though.

Comment: I have indeed seen lexical analysers that have an apostrophe-s token.

Comment: It could be a contraction of two words, as in, another way of showing two words that are still two words. But the "into one" part doesn't have to be a part of the definition of a contraction, the way it has to be a part of the definition of "compound word."

Answer (score 1):

If it has spaces or other punctuation around it, it is one word, just as hyphenated words and compound words are. Each of these list items is a single word:

- *won’t, he’ll, oughtn’t, ’tisn’t, I’d’ve, couldn’t’ve, o’rreaching, mine’ll, ain’t, durstn’t*
- *big-hearted, teeter-totter, to-morrow, now-a-days, snarf-n-barf,  wine-colored, re-elect, vis-à-vis, tête-à-tête, air-cushioned, arch-enemy, salpingo-oöphorectomy*
- *cannot, tomorrow, yesterday, nowadays, windshield, Christmas, Halloween, Michaelmas, elsewhither, grandmother, crosswalk, corkscrew, overdiversified, overreaching, breastfeed*

Comment: Source for the claim?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615016/2085).