# Grammatically correct sentence where "you're" and "your" can be interchanged?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, sentence, syntactic-analysis, contractions

Most grammar checkers are capable of detecting the the misuse of "your" and "you're"; providing the necessary correction.

I'm curious though, is there any sentence that can be constructed where replacing "your" with "you're" keeps the sentence grammatically correct, but changes the meaning?

If this is not possible, what grammar rules are in place that prevents these edge cases from occurring?

Comment: I think it would probably have to involve homonyms. _your_ would normally be followed by a noun phrase, while _you're_ is followed by a verb phrase or adjective. And it would likely be a very short construct.

Comment: @Barmar I believe the word "fine" meets the criteria. "your fine" (as in a charge) and "you're fine" are both valid fragments.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Can you make a complete sentence that's still grammatical with both phrases?

Comment: @Barmar Trivially: *I know your/you’re fine* is just one such.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I thought I remembered that too, but I misremembered: what was stuck in my memory was about "its" versus "it's". Perhaps that's what you're thinking of too?

Comment: @hvd [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/187264/63503)? I think you're right: that's probably what I was thinking of.

Comment: In honor of the Beastie Boys: Your right to party **and** you're right to party!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> a. **I love you and your bananas.**
>
> b. **I love you and you're bananas.**

This particular case depends on the *your/you're* coming after an independent clause followed by "and," since its feasibility depends on functioning either as a second direct object or as another independent clause. It also depends on the noun serving either as a thing that someone might be in possession of (the bananas we eat) or as an adjective or noun complement describing a person (bananas=crazy). Easiest if that noun is plural or uncountable.

The same sentence could be constructed with **nuts**, **garbage**, and other nouns which I'll let you brainstorm because my stormer hurts.

You can also (and thanks to @Barmar for drawing attention to this) use verbs, in which case they act as a gerund with the possessive pronoun and a present participle with the "you're." As in:

> a. **I love you and your cooking.**
>
> b. **I love you and you're cooking.**

Or:

> a. **I despise you and your smoking.**
>
> b. **I despise you and you're smoking.**

Comment: There are also numerous verbs than can be substituted.

Comment: *I know your/you’re bananas.*

Comment: The 'and' is not always necessary: I've heard your singing at the club / I've heard you're singing at the club. I can tell your family / I can tell you're family.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That should probably be posted as a separate answer, since it's a different construct.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure that this is a good question for ELU; it's either word-puzzles or a valid question on say a voice-recognition-software site.

Comment: A comma would be in the second of these cases

Comment: @Evorlor: Not necessarily. Most style guides (including Chicago Manual of Style, MLA Style Manual, and Garner's Modern American Usage) permit (if you in fact grant them authority) the omission of the comma before a coordinating conjunction separating independent clauses if those independent clauses are very short or closely connecting. I believe my independent clauses qualify as "very short."

Comment: I actually first though that "you're bananas" is funny, understanding it literally, until you explained that bananas=crazy. Thanks for explanation :)

Comment: You can also rearrange the bananas sentences - "You're bananas and I love you" vs. "Your bananas and I love you". :)

Comment: @RobWatts Except "Your bananas..." doesn't make sense in that variation because bananas don't have feelings.

Answer (score 41):

Forgive me if there's some subtlety of grammar that I've missed, but I believe the following sentence works:

> I know your fine.

I am aware of the amount of money that you have been fined. Alternatively:

> I know you're fine.

I am aware that you are doing alright.

In my opinion, both sentences would work better with a "that" inserted before your/you're, but I don't think it's strictly required.

Comment: This is also the basis for the ["grammar" meme](http://some.ly/xCnZAL) (which is really about spelling): *Grammar: the difference between knowing your shit and knowing you're shit.*

Comment: Also, "I know you're fine." = *I know you're sexy.*

Comment: @miltonaut Shouldn't there be a comma for that to work? "*I know your, sexy." And, now that I think about it, it should be "*I know your**s**, sexy.*", so perhaps I'm misunderstanding the grammatical trickery.

Comment: @camden_kid Both sentences are defined immediately after they are written.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I was just giving an additional meaning to *I know you're alright/okay* for "I know you're fine."

Comment: @miltonaut Oh, I see it now. I was misled by the equality sign, you see. Definition-wise speaking "being fine" isn't equal to "being sexy". The first is a superset to the latter. But that's a nerdy mathematics being nitpicking, so you need not to worry about that.   :)

Answer (score 39):

There's an old joke that goes like "A man walks into a psychiatrist's office. He's completely naked except that he's wrapped himself in Saran wrap. The psychiatrist takes one look at him and says 'well, I can clearly see your/you're nuts'."

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @kyle. This is one of the few jokes I've seen here that actually work as an answer. But since I have no idea what Saran wrap is (this is an international site), I have to *guess* that it's clear.

Comment: @andy256 Yes, it's a transparent, stretchy, very thin plastic material that comes in wound sheets.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Sounds like [cling wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_wrap).

Comment: @andy256 Yes, I believe saran wrap and cling wrap are both specific brands of "plastic wrap."

Comment: "Wound sheets" would be bandaids?

Comment: @TomRobinson "wound" as in the past tense of "wind"

Comment: @TomRobinson Another way to put it would be that it comes in "rolls", like a roll of aluminum foil or a roll of toilet paper.

Answer (score 27):

> Your right to believe what you want is important.

vs

> You're right to believe what you want is important.

Comment: The first one lacks the predicate, hence not being a full sentence, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Isn't the predicate of the first sentence just "is important"?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Of course. I missed that, somehow... Thanks!

Comment: I misread it the same way at first. It's easy to misparse _what you want is important_ as the object of _to believe_.

Answer (score 22):

"I know your trouble." = "I understand the trouble you have."

"I know you're trouble." = "I know that you are going to be a trouble (for me/us)."

Answer (score 16):

> You're acting like your mom.

vs

> You're acting like you're mom.

Comment: It's grammatical. Sibling A tells Sibling B, "You're acting like you're [our] mom."

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Technically in written English we conventionally capitalize "Mom" in the second instance, but it would be fine if spoken.

Comment: @user21820: I don't follow that convention though I suppose I've seen it. But yes in spoken English the distinction goes away. FWIW, in my dialect of spoken English, the two sentences are not pronounced the same either. They have different vowels and "you're" is "sesqui-syllabic", the only differences from "you are" being the timing and weakened/missing vowel from "are".

Comment: @R..: Yes in my dialect too we pronounce the way you do, but I was assuming that many people pronounce them the same, giving rise to this question in the first place. I guess not everyone follows the traditional conventions in writing as well.

Comment: Deleting my previous comment, and upvoting your post. I can't explain why I hadn't see the grammaticality in sentence No.2.

Answer (score 15):

Grammar is the difference between:

> knowing your shit

and

> knowing you’re shit

Both are correct, but obviously have very different meanings.

Comment: And etymology is a matter of knowing yore shit.

Answer (score 7):

> Your toast!

(...is getting very dark)

vs

> You're toast!

(Gotcha!)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the first one is a fragment, not a complete sentence.

Comment: You could prepend "I see" for full sentences. Also "I see your home", "I see you're home."

Answer (score 5):

greeting/insult:
It's good to see you're/your back!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a wonderful comedy sketch based entirely on your/you're confusion:

[Two Ronnies - Your Nuts, M'lord](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UepI8W6pq4)

which can be confused with the insulting *You're nuts, M'lord*!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Some **quotes from the sketch** probably would be.

Comment: Nice clip! Hope you don't mid the edit, but your post was being flagged for deletion, so I edited it to make the point clearer!:)